# interval 1 month equivalent and Microsoft Query stranges things

Tags: sql, date

In a SQL query I use actually "INTERVAL 1 MONTH" in order to get the before month.

In SQL, MYSQL this following query is working:

```
SELECT ObjectDay_2011.objectType , Sum(ObjectDay_2011.nbObjects) as 'total'
FROM DBStats.ObjectDay_2011
WHERE (ObjectDay_2011.client='TOTO') 
AND (month(ObjectDay_2011.date) = month(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
GROUP BY ObjectDay_2011.objectType 
ORDER BY Sum(ObjectDay_2011.nbObjects) DESC ;
```

But when I put it on 'Microsft Query', the tool remove my aliases!

So do you know why? 
And do you know if an equivalent of "interval 1 month" existe and do the same things?

Thanks !! :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as the aliases, see if this will help
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298955

Comment: I have alreadyu seenn this microsoft help page but my issue is, when I ads "-INTERVAL 1 MONTH" aliases disapear, but if I put "-1" alias working but the program is not efficient ;).

Comment: In MS SQL Server at least there is the DATEADD function, don't know if it will work in Query. I.e. "SELECT MONTH(DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE()));"